# Android extend ViewGroup to draw chart

Tags: android

Hello i try to create custom chart. So i try smth like this. But i can't see something at my screen. What i am do wrong? Thank you for help. I call `init` fucntion in constructor.

```
public class HorizontalBarChart extends ViewGroup {

private void init(){
    textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    textPaint.setColor(0x000);
    rectPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    rectPaint.setColor(0xFF9C27B0);
    myTextView tt = new myTextView(getContext());
    addView(tt);
}

private class myTextView extends View{

    public myTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawRect(100,100, 100,100, rectPaint);
        canvas.drawText("PRIVET", 30, 30, textPaint);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

}
}
```

in activity_main.xml

```
<smth.HorizontalBarChart
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Pie"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

might be late, but here is my comment, hope it helps, as I was just dealing with the same problem

You should tell android where to draw the myTextView instance. sth like

```
public class HorizontalBarChart extends ViewGroup {

private myTextView mView;

/* also remember to override the constructor and call init() in it! */

 private void init(){
    textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    textPaint.setColor(0x000);
    rectPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    rectPaint.setColor(0xFF9C27B0);
    mView = new myTextView(getContext());
    addView(mView);
}

private class myTextView extends View{

    public myTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawRect(100,100, 100,100, rectPaint);
        canvas.drawText("PRIVET", 30, 30, textPaint);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
     mView.layout(l, t, r, b);

}
}
```

You will probably need to override onMeasure as well, 
my suggestion:

1. you should have a compelling reason to override viewGroup, there are many viewGroups for you to use or extend,
2. with only one view, why would you extend a ViewGroup, just use your extended View.